# how to convert string into object as a key-value pair?

Tags: javascript

```
    Var a= {"fmrd":"pmc","bdr": "kmn"};
```

I have a string a and trying to convert in object as key value pair
I tried JSON.parse(), and eval but not working.. Please advice me

Comment: lot's of errors are there :P check your console

Comment: Valid JSON would look like `{"fmrd":"pmc", "bdr":"kmn"}`. You can check your JSON [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

Comment: `Var` should be `var`. If your string is in above given format than it's already a object. try `alert(a.fmrd)` it will show you `pmc`

Comment: first of all, this is not a string.

Comment: Answer is var b = [a]; now your string became json array use JSON.parse(b[0]) to convert it to object;

Answer (score 0):

First of all,  can you get rid of double quotes there?

- you need to have single quotes inside double quotes
- you need a comma after each set of properties
- you need brackets {} for the `JSON.parse` to work

So:

```
a= ""fmrd":"pmc""bdr": "kmn"";
```

would need to be

```
a= "{'fmrd':'pmc','bdr': 'kmn'}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string is wrong. it should be like as shown below.

```
var a= "{\"fmrd\":\"pmc\",\"bdr\": \"kmn\" }";
var jsonData = JSON.parse(a);
```

You can use the JSON parse method to convert this to JSON format

Answer (score 0):

your string is not in json format.

```
var a= '{"fmrd":"pmc","bdr": "kmn"}';
JSON.parse(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a= [ "fmrd":"pmc","bdr": "kmn"];

var obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

    var split = x[i].split(':');

    obj[split[0].trim()] = split[1].trim();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using map, Here is working example.

```
String test = "an:example::using:map::where:key::value:store";
        Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // split on ':' and on '::'
        String[] parts = test.split("::?");

        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i += 2) {
            m.put(parts[i], parts[i + 1]);
        }

        for (String s : m.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(s + " is " + map.get(s));
        }
```

Comment: giving a concept, you can understand logic and implement in whatever language you need.